# Dropzonejs получить file name и записать в определенном месте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) для возможности загружать файлы с перетаскиванием файлов:

```js
$("div#my-awesome-dropzone").on("success", function(file, response) {
    $('#file-name').html(response.title);
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>  
  
  
  
  <a data-fancybox data-src="#modal-file" href="javascript:;" class="btn-file">
    <span>
      Прикрепить файл(ы)
    </span>
    <span id="file-name">
    </span>
  </a>
  
  <div id="modal-file" class="modal">
    <form action="/" method="post" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
      <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message>
        <span>Выберите файлы Или просто перетащите сюда</span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**Вопрос:** Как после загрузки файла закрыть окно и отобразить имя файла в `#file-name` ?

Comment: попробуйте так: `$('#file-name').html(file.name);`

Comment: @InDevX, не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mydropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
  init: function() {
      this.on("success", function(file) {
          $('#file-name').html(file.name);
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/yedihus/edit?html,js,output  - не работает!

Comment: @HamSter, исправил, работает.

Comment: спасибо! Неправильно инициализировала!

Comment: А не подскажите ли как вывести все имена загруженных файлов? Так выводит только один.